# PHP mail function takes too much time causing increase page load time,

Tags: php

Sending email is taking significant amount of time during ajax calls.
Is it possible to send email in background and return HTTP response to user instantly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more of a server question. It depends on how you configured PHP.

It's probably fasted to use a local SMTP server that will spool the email until it's reached its destination. If you're using the same code on multiple servers, [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)  might help you to configure this from your script instead of php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX, it's working in the background already. AJAX is asynchronous, so it sends the data and continues doing anything else. Then, when the server reports a request state change, your AJAX can react accordingly.

If you're trying to give the user confirmation that the email is being sent, you can just do that right after your AJAX call. That way, the code sends the request to the server, then displays the confirmation immerdiately afterwards.

If you want to give confirmation that the email has been sent, you have to wait until, well, it has been sent. You can't display the server response before there actually is a response. Unless you did something wrong (which we can't determine without seeing your code), AJAX should handle the response immediately as soon as it arrives. So the only way to accelerate this process is to implement a more efficient/faster mail system.

Comment: I am doing multiple operation on one call including sending email.
So My page is waiting mode until ajax calls completed.

Comment: @user2768394 Ok, if I understand this correctly, your php script is doing a lot and you want to return the results first and THEN send the email. Apparently, this is not possible, as this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293389/execute-code-after-http-request-is-complete-in-php) suggests. But you could do a seperate script for the email sending and send a request to it after the first request. If you need values from the first, you can either a) return them with the first request, then send them back with the second or b) cache them b1) in a file on the server or b2) in a database.

Comment: To reduce then number of ajax calls I am doing multiple operation at the same time.

Comment: Well, php won't return the request until it's finished. I'm afraid you'll have to choose between sending 2 requests or waiting until the email has been sent. It's not possible in php to send a response to the client and still continue executing other php code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using :

[`php_exec`](https://www.php.net/function.exec) or [`fork`](https://www.php.net/pcntl_fork).

Even this question may help you: [PHP fork process - getting child output in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068434/php-fork-process-getting-child-output-in-parent)

So you emailing function can reside in some php file. And this php file should be executed either using `fork` or `exec`.